# Distinguishing Between Empty Path and No parameter

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like to create an angular SPA that has two routes:

```
http://mydomain/       <- Shows homepage
http://mydomain/2017   <- Shows results for 2017
http://mydomain/2018   <- Shows results for 2018
```

Where the `2017` and `2018` parts of the URL are parameters to a controller. I have attempted to achieve this using the following routes:

```
export const MyAppRoutes: Routes = [ 
    { path: "",  component: HomepageComponent },
    { path: ":resultId",  component: ResultComponent },
];
```

However, accessing `http://mydomain` will render the `ResultComponent`; the route parameters will simply be empty.

How can I inform the router that it should only match against `ResultComponent` if the parameter `:resultId` is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `pathMatch: full` with empty path route configuration as follows:

```
export const MyAppRoutes: Routes = [ 
    { path: "",  component: HomepageComponent, pathMatch: full },
    { path: ":resultId",  component: ResultComponent },
];
```